# Exact 1 year previous date in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a date string like this - 190515(YYMMDD) format. How to get a populate a exact one year previous date from this? ie, Expected Answer - 180515 (YYMMDD).  I am using Scala for this.

I have tried the below. But am getting the below exception - Text '190515' could not be parsed

```
 import java.time.LocalDateTime
 import java.time.format.{ DateTimeFormatter, DateTimeParseException }
 val d1 =LocalDateTime.parse("190515",DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyMMdd"))
 d1.minusYears(1)
```

Comment: parse string to date object and then subtract 1 year

Comment: Show us the code you have written and we can help sort out any problems with it. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for help on how to present your question.

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LocalDateTime` is used for points of time having both a date and a time precision. Yours only have a date, so you should be using `LocalDate`